# Subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory

We know that the group $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is the automorphism group of upper half plane of complex plane (all the biholomorphic map onto itself), the action is given by Möbius transformation. My question is, what is the abelian subgroup of it which acts properly discontinuously and freely on the upper half plane?

Answer (score 2):

A subgroup $\Gamma$ of $PSL_2(\Bbb R)$ acts
properly discontinuously on the upper half plane if and only if it is discrete. So take any discrete abelian subgroup of $PSL_2(\Bbb R)$, i.e., an abelian Fuchsian group. Note that every abelian Fuchsian group is cyclic.

Edit: Since the action also should be free, finite cyclic groups are ruled out, too.

Comment: The OP also asks for the action to be free, which rules out finite cyclic groups.