# An example of a discrete, abellian and not cyclic group in $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, mobius-transformation

There is a theorem which says that: if  $\Gamma$ is a abelian discrete subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$, then $\Gamma$ is cyclic. Nevertheless, we do not get it if the group is $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$, I mean, there is an abelian discrete subgroup which are not cyclic. The problem is that I have not managed to figure out which it is.

Comment: A continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330057/subgroup-of-psl2-mathbbr/3330067#3330067)?

Comment: There is the representation of the quaternion group $i \mapsto \pmatrix{i & 0 \\ 0 & i^{-1}},j  \mapsto \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example is given by the matrices
$$\pmatrix{1&a+bi\\0&1}$$
for $a$, $b\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

For a classification of abelian discrete subgroups of $PSL(2,\Bbb C)$ see the book
[Groups Acting on Hyperbolic Space: Harmonic Analysis and Number Theory](https://books.google.at/books?id=SgX8CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=abelian+discrete+subgroups+of+PSL_2(C)&source=bl&ots=7RfHgVd7Qw&sig=ACfU3U37cceacW4wuN1K7fATdTsaI9q4KQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwieyfuP15nkAhWQAxAIHWBHBdYQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=abelian%20discrete%20subgroups%20of%20PSL_2(C)&f=false) by Elstrodt, Grunewald and Mennicke, Theorem $1.8$ and the remark before Corollary $1.9$ on page $38-39$.